# Wampserver gives this error whan i open my webpage. getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection, wampserver, getaddrinfo

Wamp server dont connects to databse. Here is my connection code. It works okay on PC at home but Fails on Laptop on job. The thing is i cant find answer for this issue. Laptop gets DNS adresses automaticlly.

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','shop');

 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Problems With Connection To MYSQL: " .mysqli_connect_errno();
    }
```

Comment: Hello guys! if someone had this issue please give a feedback how u have resolve it.

Comment: your question is legitimate. But the moderator did not pay attentiion to your setup. When you are accessing from your laptop, then are you are trying to access your PC database server?

Comment: Do you have WAMPServer installed on the Laptop?

Comment: "I" is always uppercase in English. I won't really reopen a question which has major spelling problems, I am sorry.